# Floating point in CSH?

Tags: scripts, csh

I have been trying to run this script, but it gives the error "badly formed number"  due to the decimal 0.2224.
If I replace it with any integer, the script works fine.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set shift="-1 2  "

foreach d ($shift)
@ z = $d * "0.2224"

 awk -v k=$d 'FNR==3{$1+=4*k;}1' Lat | cat >>head
 awk -v k=$d '{$2+=k;}1' f1 | cat >>g1
 awk -v k=$d '{$2+=3*k;}1' f2 | cat >>g2
cat head g1 g2 > POSCAR-$z
rm head
rm g1
rm g2
```

Comment: Why the `bash` tag if your question is about `csh`?

Comment: Repeat after me: [I will not use csh for scripting. I will not use csh for scripting. I will not use csh for scripting.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Comment: @terdon wonderful, that made my day

Answer (score 2):

Shell variables are strings, not numbers. When you type `2` or `"0.2224"`, it is seen as a string. The shell can handle some simple data conversion, so decimal expressions may work; but floating point values will not work.

To do math in the shell, you can pipe the values through `bc` and combine that with command substitution (the backtick wrappers around the command):

```
set d = 2
set result = `echo "$d * 0.2224" | bc`
echo $result
```

The syntax of this example is written for `csh/tcsh`, but the principle works in `bash` as well. If you need something more complicated than this, you may want to implement your script in `python` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The statement " set shift="-1 2  " " causes this error "badly formed number". In csh scripts there should be space between operational characters and variables or number. So it should be " set shift = "-1 2".